# How do I migrate .Net Core Identity Tables to MySql?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a .Net Core 3.1 application that uses the Microsoft Identity Franework

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;`

The 7 tables it creates (aspnetusers etc) got created using `Add-Migration` and work just fine with a MySql back-end on localhost.

I'm trying to deploy my solution to another MySql database on my ISP, but when I use the MySql Workbench Migration wizard, I receive errors such as

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes.
SQL Error: 1071
```

When I hack up these 255 character fields to be smaller, I start getting Foreign Key constraint errors, even when I re-order the tables so that the foreign keys don't get created until after the tables they depend upon are created.

Does anyone know how I can migrate the identity tables to my ISP's database?  I tried to get around it (even though I'd lose data) by doing the following `Update-Database -Migration AddIdentityTables -Context = "MyDbContext"` but that does nothing since the migration has already been applied and it won't let me specify a connection string to the ISP's database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to force the migration, but it was painful.  I did it in 2 steps:

1. Migrate the `aspnetusers` and `aspnetroles` tables first
2. Migrate all the rest of the tables since they have foreign keys `aspnetroleclaims, aspnetuserclaims, aspnetuserlogins, aspnetuserroles, aspnetusertokens`

But one of the gotchas is that Microsoft's Identity table fields are all varchar(255), at least when you let .Net Core scaffolding create them.  I have no idea what datatypes it generates if you use SQL Server, but it's varchar(255) for MySQL using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.

So when using the MySql Workbench Migration Wizard and you get to the Manual Editing stage, you  have to choose "Column Mappings" from the drop down and manually change all the VARCHAR(255) in the target fields to VARCHAR(100).

Make sure to click on "Show Code and Messages" in order to change the length of the Foreign Key fields to 100 for each table as well.

Then just go through with the Migration Wizard for each of steps 1 & 2 above and it all works.

A better way to do this is probably to let the Migration Wizard generate the 2 .sql files for you.  Then just find and replace 255 with 100 and run each script consecutively.

I am sure this can't be the best way to solve my problem, but it worked.

Note:  Now I'm limited to usernames, emails and roles that are 100 characters or less, but for what I'm doing that's plenty.

Comment: I used this solutions too, I changed all VARCHAR(255) to VARCHAR(100) and that worked well until the create "AspNetUserTokens" probably because of this :  `table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name })` I can change the VARCHAR(100) in VARCHAR(30) and that will work, but that look pretty small. does someone have an idea to correct this in another way?